# Storage Event Trigger does not work when I upload file in Datalake using Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have created a storage event trigger to trigger a pipeline in Azure Data Factory. This trigger works when I manually put a file in the datalake. But when the file is uploaded from Azure Function, trigger doesn't work.

Below is my function to upload file in datalake.

```
public void UploadFileToDatalake(FileUpload file, string containerSasUri, string stage, string dir, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("inside uploadFileTodatalake");
            UriBuilder sasUri = new UriBuilder(containerSasUri);
            DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(sasUri.Uri);

            string container = Globals._transientContainer;
            var fileSystemClient = dataLakeServiceClient.GetFileSystemClient(container);

            string pathFileDL = file.Name;
            
            string directory = dir;

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
            sw.Write(File.ReadAllText(file.FullPath));
            sw.Flush();
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            file.Content = ms;

            DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient = fileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient(directory);
            try
            {
                if (directoryClient.Exists())
                {
                    log.LogInformation(directoryClient.Name);
                    DataLakeFileClient fileClient = directoryClient.CreateFile(pathFileDL); // 0kb blob
                    file.Content.Position = 0;
                    fileClient.Upload(file.Content, true);
                    log.LogInformation($"{stage}: {file.Name} uploaded to {pathFileDL}");
                    file.Content.Close();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                //fileSystemClient.Delete();
            }
        }
```

FileUpload is a model class I am using.

```
public class FileUpload
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Stream Content { get; set; }
        public string FullPath { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I realized my mistake here. FlieClient first creates an empty blob then writes into the blob. Which was causing a problem with trigger. So instead of FileClient, I used BlobClient and it got resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am tried with [the blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-container-and-upload-blob-using-azure-function-in-net-core/)  for ***upload a file*** in azure blob using `azure function`.

Before creation of azure function, I was created the pipeline `Storage Event Trigger` to get trigger when the ***new file arrives/created*** on ***storage blob***.

Tried with **manually** to *uploading* a file using `azure portal`. The event grid ***triggered***.

After created and published the `azure function` on azure. Now run the azure function. It generates the random files on storage container and the expected Storage Event Trigger also run. I can see the Triggered output on the portal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I used BlobClient instead of FileClient. Changed nuget. And it worked.

Comment: Thanks @NikitaM. I am also suggest to use BlobClient for further information [check this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-container-and-upload-blob-using-azure-function-in-net-core/).

Answer (score 1):

By using ADLS FileClient, you should set Close option to true. Then the Storage Event will be sent yet another time after the upload stream was closed.

```
        var options = new DataLakeFileUploadOptions();
        options.Close = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

I realized my mistake here. FlieClient first creates an empty blob then writes into the blob. Which was causing a problem with trigger. So instead of FileClient, I used BlobClient and it got resolved.